# Script for toggling OS X "Show Hidden Files" in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Is there a way to toggle the hidden files visibility on/off with a terminal script?

In pseudocode:

> if can view hidden files
>
> set com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles false
>
> else
>
> set com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true
>
> killall Finder

Comment: To be clear, you would like to use a *Terminal/shell script* to control hidden file visibility in the *Finder*, correct? If so, please clarify your question.

Comment: Note that in *Open File* dialogs, you can show hidden files using `Cmd-Shift-.`. In many cases, this should be good enough.

Comment: @DanielBeck that trick is extremely useful. thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

k="com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles"
b=$(defaults read $k 2>&1 /dev/null)
[[ "$b" == 1 ]] && b=false || b=true
defaults write $k -bool $b
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder"
quit
delay 0.2
launch
activate
end'
```

Or an AppleScript version:

```
set k to "com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
set r to do shell script "defaults read " & k
do shell script "defaults write " & k & " -bool " & (r is 0 as text)
tell application "Finder"
    quit
    delay 0.2
    launch
    delay 0.2
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

[AppleScript](http://www.easyclasspage.de/mac/seite-18.html) or a [shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206008/toggle-appleshowallfiles-with-a-simple-bash-script)?

Of course I like [the widget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) best.